# Too many mandatory fields in aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an aggregate called Order which has a big list (upwards of 20) of fields that the Business has identified as mandatory fields.

An order cannot be in a valid state without these mandatory fields.

In my domain layer, when I create the Order aggregate, there is some domain logic involved which requires just a few of these 20 mandatory fields (just about 5-6 are required for the domain logic).

If I go purely by the principles of DDD and treat these mandatory values as invariants, I have to create my Order domain object with all fields, most of which should merely pass a not-null/empty validation. It does feel like there could be a better way to handle this scenario.

So what should be my approach? Should I create the domain object with just those 5-6 fields that are required for domain logic? Wouldn't that mean the Order aggregate is then in an invalid state from a business perspective? But the domain object is much simpler if created with a smaller set of values.

I have checked with the Business about whether they really require all those fields, and yes, they have a very real need for an order to be created with all those mandatory fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301928/aggregate-root-with-many-fields

From the link above:

*Think of it this way: while you order something from an e-commerce website you might be filling out your order in several distinct steps, going through a number of screens to enter the products, shipping information, payment information, etc... 
The order is saved in between steps, even though it is lacking in the needed information to fullfill the order!* ***The only difference is that before an order can be shipped it needs that information. It does not mean that it cannot be created.***